# What event can I use to detect changes to DataGridViewRow.Visible?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

I have a custom control which uses `DataGridViewRow` and has a notion of 'child' rows that should disappear when the parent row's visibility is set to false. Is there an option (besides subclassing `DataGridViewRow` to override the `Visible` property) which can be used to detect changes to this property on my `DataGridViewRow`s? I don't see an event directly, but I am wondering if there is a different event elsewhere that perhaps I could somehow leverage.

Edit: The question is not "off topic". "What event can I use to detect changes to DataGridViewRow.Visible?" is a direct question about the official `DataGridView` libaries in the .NET framework.

Comment: Did you write code to make the rows invisible?  Then you already know where this happens.

Comment: I don't see any event in a DGV you could use, so you best hook it into the code that actually hides and shows the rows. [DataGridViewRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) itself of course doesn't even have an event model..

Comment: I already have code that makes it work, but if someone uses my class to set `Visible` on a row directly, it won't affect children properly. I wanted to know if there was a better way.

Comment: You are talking about code we can't see.  If you have a parent row that the user can set invisible, then you have to write code to make the children invisible, too.

Comment: I have that code. I'm saying that I want to trigger the code automatically whenever a user of the class changes the `Visible` property on a row.

Comment: How does the user change the Visible property on a row?  Do you have a checkbox or something?

Comment: @Missy: Not an end user. When a developer using my library calls `row.Visible`, which I currently do not prevent them from doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going out to the parent DataGridView, there is the [DataGridView.RowStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowstatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event, which contains `e.Row` and `e.StateChanged.Visible`.